# Authenticate with either a token or Open ID Connect in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Similar to how an app can offer authentication via either in-built forms or an external Identity Provider, I'd like to have two authentication options for my web site; In this case a custom token (eg API key) passed in the Authorization header that will be used if verified, and if none found or not valid then Open ID Connect. Cookie Auth for either will then keep a session.

I can get either working separately, but how do I combine them to achieve the above?

The following are the separate implementations.

Both have `app.UseAuthentication();` in the `Configure` method in Startup.cs.

The **Open ID implementation** has only the following in the `ConfigureServices` method in Startup.cs, plus the `[Authorize]` attribute on each controller method I want auth on:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, policy =>
        policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Authentication, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme));
    options.AddPolicy(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, policy =>
        policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Authentication, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme));
});

services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(o =>
{
    o.LoginPath = "/security/accessdenied";
    o.AccessDeniedPath = "/security/accessdenied";
})
.AddOpenIdConnect(o =>
{
    o.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.ClientId = oidcClientId;
    o.Authority = oidcAuthority;
    o.Scope.Add("openid");
    o.Scope.Add("profile");
    o.Scope.Add("email");
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        // Set what is populated in User.Identity.Name
        NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.Email
    };
});
```

That's the end of the Open ID Connect implementation.

For the **custom SAS Token implementation**, there's a few pieces...
I have a custom `AuthenticationHandler` like so:

```
public class SasTokenAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<SasTokenAuthOptions>
{
    public SasTokenAuthHandler(IOptionsMonitor<SasTokenAuthOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        // get token and parse
        // ...

        if (tokenExists)
        {
            // verify token
            // ...

            if (isVerifiedAndCurrent)
            {
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Authentication, SasTokenAuthOptions.Scheme)
                });

                var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                result = AuthenticateResult.Success(new AuthenticationTicket(claimsPrincipal, SasTokenAuthOptions.Scheme));

                // Create cookie
                var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties()
                {
                    ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(10)
                };
                await Context.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, claimsPrincipal, authProperties);
            }
            else
            {
                result = AuthenticateResult.Fail("Could not verify signed data");
            }
        }

        return await Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```

In the Startup.cs file:

```
services.AddScheme<SasTokenAuthOptions, SasTokenAuthHandler>(SasTokenAuthOptions.Scheme, options =>
{
    var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    options.Logger = provider.GetService<Serilog.ILogger>();
    options.SasTokenService = provider.GetService<SasTokenService>();
    options.CustomApiAuthSettings = provider.GetService<SasTokenAuthSettings>();
});
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(SasTokenAuthOptions.Scheme, policy => 
        policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Authentication, SasTokenAuthOptions.Scheme));
    options.AddPolicy(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, policy =>
        policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Authentication, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme));
});
services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = SasTokenAuthOptions.Scheme;
})
.AddCookie(o =>
{
    o.LoginPath = "/security/accessdenied";
    o.AccessDeniedPath = "/security/accessdenied";
})
```

And on each controller method I require authentication on:

```
[Authorize(SasTokenAuthOptions.Scheme)]
```

Perhaps of note: I've noticed if I just have `[Authorize]` then the SAS Token auth doesn't work but I'm not sure why.

That's the end of the custom SAS Token implementation.

I've tried adding both sets of code in `Startup.cs` but Open ID Connect is always what is used.

Comment: I would highly recommend Dominick Baier's and Brock Allen's Identity Server 4: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.  This might have everything you need and much more.

Comment: @cloudstrifebro this web app isn't wanting to be an identity provider, it's trying to offer an alternative auth option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the auth handler code has changed from that in the question, but once corrected, then instead of using policies configure the auth services as specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x). Thatis, don't include a default scheme but instead specify all schemes in the Authorize attribute with comma separation. Eg.

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = AuthSchemes)]
public class MixedController : Controller
    private const string AuthSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme + "," + JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme + "," + OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
```

I've noticed that the scheme you want to challenge the user (eg redirect) should be the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Authorize constructor take policy name but you want custom authentication.
Use AuthenticationSchemes property

Update:
Try this

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes= SasTokenAuthOptions.Scheme)]
```

Comment: I don't follow, could you possibly elaborate with an example?

Comment: Sorry for being late, are you still at or found a work around?

Comment: I haven't been able to implement both yet.